# Calculate semi axes of an ellipse

Tags: geometry

Given two line segments in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (from $a$ to $b$ and from $c$ to $d$)

$$\varphi:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2, \quad s\mapsto a+s(b-a)$$
$$\psi:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2, \quad t\mapsto c+t(d-c)$$

a fixed (Euclidean) distance $\varepsilon$ of point pairs on these line segments defines a filled ellipse intersected by the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$:

$$W_{\varphi,\psi} := \{(s,t)\in[0,1]^2\;|\;d(\varphi(s),\psi(t)) \le \varepsilon\}$$

In the following picture you can see the line segments $\varphi$ and $\psi$ on the left and the parameter space $[0,1]^2$ on the right, intersected by the filled ellipse $W_{\varphi,\psi}$ (white):

[image: lines and parameter space]

The border of this ellipse is given by

$$\{(s,t)\in[0,1]^2\;|\;d(\varphi(s),\psi(t))=\varepsilon\}$$

or, more verbose:

$$d(\varphi(s),\psi(t)) = \sqrt{\begin{array}{rccl}
&(a_1+s(b_1-a_1)&-&(c_1+t(d_1-c_1)))^2 \\
+&(a_2+s(b_2-a_2)&-&(c_2+t(d_2-c_2)))^2
\end{array}} = \varepsilon$$

**Question:** is there a way to directly calculate the semi axes and/or position of foci from the four points $a,b,c,d$? I'm *believing* the center of the ellipses is the parameter pair $(s,t)\in\{\mathbb{R}\cup\pm\infty\}^2$ of the intersection of the two lines through $a,b$ and $c,d$.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to see how this works is to simplify the problem and assume that the two lines are perpendicular and align with coordinate axes.  That is, assume $c_1=d_1$ and $a_2=b_2$, for example, and you will get

$$[(b_1-a_1) s+(a_1-c_1)]^2 + [(d_2-c_2) t - (a_2-c_2)]^2 = \epsilon^2$$

Now, I hope you see that this describes an ellipse having center

$$\left (-\frac{a_1-c_1}{\epsilon} , \frac{a_2-c_2}{\epsilon} \right )$$

and semiaxes

$$\ell_s = \frac{\epsilon}{b_1-a_1}$$
$$\ell_t = \frac{\epsilon}{d_2-c_2}$$

In the general case, you can rotate the axes so as to eliminate the cross-term $s t$.  I leave the algebra to you.

Comment: Hey Ron, thanks for your reply! I thought the intersection of the two induced lines $(c_1=d_1,a_2=b_2)$ would give me the ellipse's center $\left(s=\frac{d_1-a_1}{b_1-a_1},t=\frac{a_2-d_2}{c_2-d_2}\right)$ which doesn't depend on $\varepsilon$ - could you please explain what $\varepsilon$ does with the ellipse's center?

Comment: @memowe: Not sure how you came to that conclusion; can you explain some?

Comment: You can look at the function $d_{\varphi,\psi}:[0,1]^2\to\mathbb{R}^{\ge0},(s,t)\mapsto d(\varphi(s),\psi(t))$ which has a minimum ($0$) at that intersection point parameter pair, if it exists. The described ellipses (intersected with $[0,1]^2$) are the origins $d_{\varphi,\psi}^{-1}(\varepsilon)$ which all have the same center $d_{\varphi,\psi}^{-1}(0)=\{(s_\times,t_\times)\}$ for $(s_\times,t_\times)$ being the parameter pair of an intersection (if it exists). Look at my simple visualization http://netzverwaltung.info/freespace.html (drag+drop the points, darker: higher values, white: $0$).

Comment: @memowe: nice app.  But what is the question now?  Why does the center of an ellipse depend on $\epsilon$? What is $\epsilon$?  It seems to me that your ellipse def is the locus of $s$ and $t$ on the given lines that satisfy a distance constraint, i.e., they are $\epsilon$ apart.  And my method parametrizes over $s$ and $t$, which are not really visually related to the space in which your ellipses and lines live.  Rather, $s$ and $t$ are orthogonal axes here.  Maybe that's why you are confused about the lines - there are two separate pictures.

Comment: Again, thanks for your time! The ellipse lives in the parameter space of pairs $(s,t)\in[0,1]^2$ and is defined as all parameter pairs $(s,t)$ for which the distance $d(\varphi(s),\psi(t))$ of points on the line segments is a given $\varepsilon$. The ellipse doesn't live in the space where the line segments live. The question is how to calculate the semi axes of that ellipse in the parameter space.